# Postgres connection error in ubuntu and centos

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, centos7

I am new to postgres. While connecting through ubuntu and centos I'm getting this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to all host by editing ipv4 entry in pg_hba.conf file.
After modification restart postgresql service.